# Debug your functions while running unit tests?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am using Visual Studio 2022; when I click "Test -> Run All Tests," the breakpoints in the code that is actually being tested are not being hit. If I click "Test -> Debug All Tests," it debugs just the test method and not my actual code. I want to debug the actual code. Is there any way to do that? There is an answer that says I could do that using 'Tests in Current Context' option but I can't seem to find that.

Comment: I usually put break point in main project where it call another project.  Then use step to get into other projects.  Once inside another project you can add additional break points.  To debug with source code (not assembly) you need to pdb file in the bin folder(s) which contains debug info.

Comment: Check if your builds/dlls are up to date if they're in a different solution and if they're build using debug (-> pdb files), not release build config. If a used dll is not equal to the code being debugged, it won't hit the break point

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a breakpoint in your actual code? if you do, IDE will hit that point in your code while the test is running.